# Setting a while loop that validates input?

Tags: java, loops

I have a user setting the amount of questions there should be. they need to choose between 2 and 5

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many questions? (2-5)");
int size = sc.nextInt();
```

I want to make it so if they put in less than 2 and more than 5 it makes them try again. Is is something like  this-

```
if(size < 2 || size >5) {
     System.out.println("Error, has to be 2-5");
        continue;
```

Because I'm getting errors when I plug that in

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: while, do-while?

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is used when you have a loop and you want to go the next iteration of the loop without executing the lines that come after `continue`
Since you dont have a loop and you are still using a continue, that is why you are getting an error

You can use a while loop to achieve what you want

```
while(size < 2 || size >5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many questions? (2-5)");

int size = 0;
size = sc.nextInt();

while(size < 2 || size > 5){
     //reprompt the user for input
     System.out.println("Must be between 2 and 5. How many questions? (2-5)");
     size = sc.nextInt();
}
// proceed further
```